# text alignment shortcut RTL and LTR

Tags: macos, keyboard, text, text-input

When in text box in any application, such as search text boxes, address fields in Finder and Safari, or even inside sites such as Google's search text box:

I use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to switch the language with which I type. But I want also to switch from right-to-left to left-to-right. How do I do that on Mac with and without a shortcut?

Comment: @TomGewecke thanks. I tried your suggestion. It works in some text boxes, like the "find" text box that appears when hitting cmd + f in the browser. It didn't work in text boxes that show up inside sites (such as Google Search and this comment's text box...).

Comment: Your answer is: [enter link description here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129216/rtl-right-align-in-text-boxes)