# RTL + Right-align in text boxes

Tags: keyboard, text, text-input

In Windows, I could use Ctrl+Shift to align text in textboxes. To align left, I used the left Ctrl and the left Shift and the right ones to align to the right.

Is there a way to do this in OSX?

Comment: Are you talking about text boxes in general or in a certain app?

Comment: @grgarside In general.

Comment: "Ctrl+Shift to align text in text boxes" What is your concept of a text box? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @CousinCocaine Any field that I can use to input text. The equivalent in HTML is inputs of type text and textareas.

Comment: @OmervanKloeten, I just happend to have Windows 7 running in a virtual machine, but what you describe does not work (tested in ie address bar, web-forms, windows-start-menu, etc). You might have some add-ons installed. -1 for this question as it is unclear what you ask and does not work as you describe. Can you put a video or link in your question that explains this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

⌃⌥⌘→ (control-option-command-right) makes the selection left to right
⌃⌥⌘← (control-option-command-left) makes the selection right to left
⌃⌘→ (control-command-right) makes the paragraph left to right
⌃⌘← (control-command-left) makes the paragraph right to left

If you didn't choose a right-to-left input source as the default input source when you created your account, you might have to enable the shortcuts from System Preferences:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly (though not globally)!

Comment: I enabled keyboard shortcuts but neither of these work